# Casting generic with inner type as interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7NWbNM)

```cs
using System;

interface Interface { }
class Outer<T> : Interface
    where T : Interface { }
class Inner : Interface { }

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Type outer = typeof(Outer<>);
        Type inner = typeof(Inner);
        Type expectedType = typeof(Outer<Interface>);
        Type final = outer.MakeGenericType(inner);

        // This works
        Inner innerInstance = (Inner)Activator.CreateInstance(inner);

        // This works
        Outer<Inner> outerInstance = (Outer<Inner>)Activator.CreateInstance(final);

        // We can cast the real type
        Interface interfaceInstance = innerInstance;

        // But we cant cast with the interface as the inner type
        Outer<Interface> casted = (Outer<Interface>)outerInstance;
    }
}
```

This cast will fail `(Outer<Interface>)outerInstance;` as it doesn't recognise the inner type as Interface.
Is there any way to force or conver it into the type `Outer<Interface>` rather than `Outer<Inner>`?

Comment: No. What you're asking for is *generic variance* and it doesn't apply to classes.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed the types because types named `Interface`, `Inner`, and `Outer<T>` scramble my brain. Hopefully this makes the relationships between types easier to see.

```cs
interface IAnimal { }

class Dog : IAnimal { }

class PetStore<T> : IAnimal where T : IAnimal
{}
```

And when we simplify it, the question is why won't the compiler let us do this?

```cs
PetStore<IAnimal> casted = new PetStore<Dog>();
```

Every `Dog` is an `IAnimal`, so why can't we do this?

There's always something that the compiler is protecting us from. Sometimes it's hard to figure out what that something is.

It becomes clearer if we add a little bit to `PetStore<T>` and another class:

```cs
class PetStore<T> : IAnimal where T : IAnimal
{
    private List<T> _pets = new List<T>();

    public void Add(T foo)
    {
        _pets.Add(foo);
    }
}

class Cat : IAnimal { }
```

If we have an instance of `PetStore<Dog>` then the inner list contains items of types `Dog`. Every item we add to the list must be of type `Dog`.

If we could cast this as `PetStore<IAnimal>` then we could do this:

```cs
var dogStore = new PetStore<Dog>();
PetStore<IAnimal> animalStore = (PetStore<IAnimal>)dogStore;
animalStore.Add(new Cat())
```

Now we can see what the compiler is preventing. `dogStore` is a `PetStore<Dog>`. Every item in the `_pets` list must be a `Dog`.

But by casting the object as `PetStore<IAnimal>` we would make it possible to add a `Cat` to the list, because `Cat` is an `IAnimal`. That wouldn't make any sense. It's a `List<Dog>`, so how could we add something to the list that isn't a `Dog`?

---

Here's an even simpler version that illustrates the issue with less noise:

```cs
var dogs = new List<Dog>();
var animals = (List<IAnimal>)dogs; // this won't compile.
animals.Add(new Cat());
```

We may have tried to do this at some point. The compiler doesn't allow it for exactly the same reason. It would allow us to create a `List<Dog>` and then add something to it that's *not* a `Dog`.

We might reason that we would never try to add a `Cat` to the list because we know it's only supposed to contain dogs. But in that case why cast the `List<Dog>` as a `List<IAnimal>` in the first place?

Also, what if we have a method like this:

```cs
void DoSomethingWithListOfAnimals(List<IAnimal> animals)
```

If we could cast our `List<Dog>` as a `List<IAnimal>` then we could pass it as an argument to this method. The code in this method has no way of knowing that this list was only supposed to contain dogs. It just knows that it has a `List<IAnimal>`.

It's helpful if we can understand *why* the compiler won't let us do something. But for practical purposes the compiler is always right. If it won't let us do something there's a reason.